# Unable to install Next JS on project

Tags: npm, next.js, npx

I am trying to install NextJS latest for a project I am going to work on, however I am unable to, I tried to run the following command:

npx create-next-app@latest ./

I have the latest version of Node installed on my machine, but I am getting the below error on my terminal:

npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/dmanca/.npm/_npx/cc2145a2fe1558fa/node_modules/create-next-app
npm ERR! dest /Users/dmanca/.npm/_npx/cc2145a2fe1558fa/node_modules/.create-next-app-GAACda7M
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/Users/dmanca/.npm/_npx/cc2145a2fe1558fa/node_modules/create-next-app' -> '/Users/dmanca/.npm/_npx/cc2145a2fe1558fa/node_modules/.create-next-app-GAACda7M'

I tried to check within the user I am trying to install Next from, but I am unsure what to check exactly.